# PostGis ST_Distance_Spheroid confusion

Tags: postgresql, distance, postgis, map-projections

I am new to POstGis so this question might seem simple but I am really stuck. 
So I have a table in which there are 4 important row: startLon, startLat, endLon, endLat which are all in double precision type.

The first row holds coordinates (this 2 points is 7m apart):

```
StartLon: 103.776047
StartLat: 1.292149
EndLon:  103.776070
EndLat: 1.292212
```

When I try to calculte the distance between 2 point in each row using:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Spheroid(
                ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || StartLon || ' ' || Startlat || ')',4326),
                ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || EndLon || ' ' || Endlat || ')',4326),
                'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
FROM i3_building.floordata;
```

The result is:

```
2.87254682929478
```

Which is not correct

But when I tried to do it manually:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Spheroid(
                ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(103.776047, 1.292149),4326),
                ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(103.77607, 1.292212),4326),
                'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]');
```

The result given out is correct:

```
7.42160512978493
```

All of the coordinate are found using GoogleMap so the SRID should be 4326.
Please help me out, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just realize that the result 2.872 ... is not the result of the first line 
If I don't order the result with some key like id, then the result come out will be random. Learn that from a nice co-worker :) Hope it help any other people who are beginner to PostGIS like me.